# Specify Specific Identity file when ssh'ing as certain user in ~/.ssh/config

Tags: linux, ssh, command, ssh-config

I would like to specify a specific identity file based on the user I am ssh'ing as to a server.

For example when ssh as user1 from host 1 to host 2 as user1

```
[user1@host1 ~]$ ssh user1@host2
```

I would like to use a certain identity file.  However when I ssh as user1 from host1 to host2 as user2, I would like to use a different identity file

```
[user1@host1 ~]$ ssh user2@host2
```

Now, I can do this by specifying the identity file in the command,

```
[user1@host1 ~]$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_user1 user1@host2

[user1@host1 ~]$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_user2 user2@host2
```

but I would love to do it in my ~/.ssh/config file.  I tried the following, but it does not seem to work

```
Host user2@*
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_user2

Host user1@*
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_user1
```

Any and all help is appreciated.  If this has to be configured somewhere else, that is fine as well.  I would just like to avoid specifying it on the command line.  Would really love to figure this out as it would be a cool solution to my problem!

Comment: The path in your config file and the path you are using on the command line do not match.  Which one is correct?  Do things work as expected when using the correct path?  What is the output of `ls ~/.ssh`?

Comment: That was a typo.  Will fix that now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the `Match` directive e.g.

```
Host host2
  HostName host2.some.dom.ain
  Match user user1  
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_user1  
  Match user user2
    Identityfile ~/.ssh/id_user2
```

Comment: Sweet!  That worked perfectly.  I saw some stuff about the match directive in my research, but it looked like it was only for the sshd config.     Thanks